# Generating a list of random numbers, summing to 1

Tags: python, random

- This question is not a duplicate of [Getting N random numbers whose sum is M](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2640053/7758804) because:

  1. **Most** answers there are about theory, not a specific coding solution in python to answer this question
  2. The accepted answer here is 5 years older than the one answer in the duplicate that answers this question.
  3. The duplicate accepted answer does not answer this question

---

How would I make a list of N (say 100) random numbers, so that their sum is 1?

I can make a list of random numbers with

```
r = [ran.random() for i in range(1,100)]
```

How would I modify this so that the list sums to 1 (this is for a probability simulation).

Comment: Do the numbers need to be within a certain range themselves (e.g., non-negative)?

Comment: If their sum is 1, they are not completely random.

Comment: Divide each number in list by sum of the list

Comment: @aragaer I was just going to suggest that. Normalize the elements. :)

Comment: aragear please post an answer. So we can upvote the person with the idea.

Comment: @Bogdan that's not really an issue.

Comment: @aragaer I think I need to stop for the day.

Comment: @Bogdan that's not correct.  They are random, but one degree of freedom is used up by the constraint.

Comment: @pjs, which means that (at best) 99 of them are random and 1 is not. In other words, "not completely random".

Comment: @pjs so sorry, I didn't stumble across that one when searching.

Comment: @Bogdan and why would that be an issue worth bringing up?

Comment: It's not an issue, it's a comment. It could be an issue, depending on what @Tom needed these numbers for.

Comment: @Bogdan No, it couldn't be an issue because whatever Tom needs the numbers for will, by definition the definition of the problem, be bounded by 99 degrees of freedom.

Comment: Consider updating the answer to be @sega_sai's answer.

Comment: Just out if idle interest, what are you simulating? Normalizing to 1.00 is a lot more common for probability distributions than for random samples. Just trying to imagine the use case ...

Answer (score 226, accepted):

The simplest solution is indeed to take N random values and divide by the sum.

A more generic solution is to use the [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)
which is [available in numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html).

By changing the parameters of the distribution you can change the "randomness" of individual numbers

```
>>> import numpy as np, numpy.random
>>> print np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(10),size=1)
[[ 0.01779975  0.14165316  0.01029262  0.168136    0.03061161  0.09046587
   0.19987289  0.13398581  0.03119906  0.17598322]]

>>> print np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(10)/1000.,size=1)
[[  2.63435230e-115   4.31961290e-209   1.41369771e-212   1.42417285e-188
    0.00000000e+000   5.79841280e-143   0.00000000e+000   9.85329725e-005
    9.99901467e-001   8.37460207e-246]]

>>> print np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(10)*1000.,size=1)
[[ 0.09967689  0.10151585  0.10077575  0.09875282  0.09935606  0.10093678
   0.09517132  0.09891358  0.10206595  0.10283501]]
```

Depending on the main parameter the Dirichlet distribution will either give vectors where all the values are close to 1./N where N is the length of the vector, or give vectors where most of the values of the vectors will be ~0 , and there will be a single 1, or give something in between those possibilities.

EDIT (5 years after the original answer): Another useful fact about the Dirichlet distribution is that you naturally get it, if you generate a Gamma-distributed set of random variables and then divide them by their sum.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to mention the Dirichlet distribution. This should be the answer.

Comment: I've changed my accepted answer to this one, as scaling doesn't necessarily give a uniform distribution.

Comment: @Tom, I don't begrudge your choice, and this answer is nice, but I want to make something clear: Scaling _does_ necessarily give a uniform distribution (over `[0,1/s)`). It will be exactly as uniform as the unscaled distribution you started with, because scaling doesn't change the distribution, but just compresses it.  This answer gives a variety of distributions, only one of which is uniform.  If this doesn't make sense to you, run the examples and look at some histograms to make it clear.  Also try the same thing with a gaussian distribution (`np.random.normal`).

Comment: @askewchan, you are not correct here. taking random numbers and dividing by the sum will NOT give the uniform distribution(it will be close to uniform for very large N, but never strictly uniform and also not uniform at all at smaller N). The Dirichlet distribution will not give the uniform distributions either (because it is impossible to get uniform distributions and sum of 1).

Comment: @sega_sai In that vein, there is no strictly uniform distribution that can be pseudo-randomly generated.  What I mean is that renormalizing a 'uniform' distribution doesn't make it any less uniform.  I was responding to Tom's comment that implied this answer was selected because he wanted a uniform distribution.  Unless I'm more fundamentally mistaken?

Comment: @askewchan Renormalizing uniform distribution by the sum of numbers which include the original number makes the distribution non-uniform. (it is easy to see even with two numbers)

Comment: @sega_sai It's not easy to see for me. It changes the interval of the distribution but I don't see how it redistributes it to be non-uniform.

Comment: @askewchan The simplest way is to figure out is to just plot the histogram from your example for N=2 -- you'll see that the distribution will look triangular like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37061/discussion-between-askewchan-and-sega-sai)

Comment: @askewchan If you guys came to any conclusion I'd be really interested to know.

Comment: @Tom, sorry, I'm still confused, and sega_sai never came to my chat :(

Comment: @askewchan Sorry, didn't have time for that.

Comment: I think "...to take N random values..." should be "...to take N exponentially distributed random values...", for example, with `random.expovariate`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for.  But maybe not quite... Is there a way to get a pdf that produces samples that tend towards a certain mean distribution (where each element is not 1/N) and then adjust the amount of variation from that? (while still summing to 1).

Comment: I think the non-scientific answer to my question above is to scale the alpha values.  I.e. `v*alpha` where high `v` results in low variance to the mean sample distribution (`alpha/sum(alpha)`) and low `v` means high variance.

Comment: @sega_sai hey im just learnings, and want to thank you for doing this. i have a question: if i use: ```a = np.array([400, 400, 400,400])``` ```d = np.random.dirichlet(a,1000)``` and then i plot it as a histogram with ```plt.hist(d)``` it really fits into a normal distribution.  is that because of how the generator works, or how this distribution is set up?  thanks

Comment: @sega_sai it looks very similar to this: ```norm = randoms.normal(0.25,0.01,(400*4,4))```

Answer (score 46):

The best way to do this is to simply make a list of as many numbers as you wish, then divide them all by the sum.  They are totally random this way.

```
r = [ran.random() for i in range(1,100)]
s = sum(r)
r = [ i/s for i in r ]
```

or, as suggested by @TomKealy, keep the sum and creation in one loop:

```
rs = []
s = 0
for i in range(100):
    r = ran.random()
    s += r
    rs.append(r)
```

For the fastest performance, use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random(100)
a /= a.sum()
```

And you can give the random numbers any distribution you want, for a probability distribution:

```
a = np.random.normal(size=100)
a /= a.sum()
```

---- Timing ----

```
In [52]: %%timeit
    ...: r = [ran.random() for i in range(1,100)]
    ...: s = sum(r)
    ...: r = [ i/s for i in r ]
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop

In [53]: %%timeit
   ....: rs = []
   ....: s = 0
   ....: for i in range(100):
   ....:     r = ran.random()
   ....:     s += r
   ....:     rs.append(r)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.9 µs per loop

In [54]: %%timeit
   ....: a = np.random.random(100)
   ....: a /= a.sum()
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: @Tom No worries, it's easy to get stuck trying to make these things a lot harder than they are :)  Now it's here for the next person.

Comment: I think it's time for beer.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it seems like there should be a way to do this in a single pass that gets a good distribution across the range.  Create, sum, modify is a 3 pass operation.  You could at least optimize away one pass by summing as you generate though.

Comment: @Silas True, you could do one loop and keep a running sum. I think the numpy solution would be faster though, and if one is doing probability distribution work, it's likely that the dependency would be useful elsewhere.

Comment: @Silas I'm no expert, but probably not. Mainly it's faster since the array operations are faster than python loops.

Comment: Scaling is not necessarily good.  See my answer for more.  There are many possible mappings from [0,1)^n onto the target space (sum of x_i = 1) and they can't all be uniform!

Comment: @Mike, agreed. The outcome of my answer has a uniform distribution on `[0,1/N)`.  But at first glance, I don't believe this is an issue for more natural distributions without a hard upper limit, for example the normal distribution, which can be renormalized without hard boundaries.

Comment: **This is wrong**, at least in case you care about actual uniform distributions https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068956/2075003

Comment: Thank you for that link, @n1000! That answer is the first explanation that clarified this issue to me!

Answer (score 8):

Dividing each number by the total may not give you the distribution you want.  For example, with two numbers, the pair x,y = random.random(), random.random() picks a point uniformly on the square 0<=x<1, 0<=y<1.  Dividing by the sum "projects" that point (x,y) onto the line x+y=1 along the line from (x,y) to the origin.  Points near (0.5,0.5) will be much more likely than points near (0.1,0.9).

For two variables, then, x = random.random(), y=1-x gives a uniform distribution along the geometrical line segment.

With 3 variables, you are picking a random point in a cube and projecting (radially, through the origin), but points near the center of the triangle will be more likely than points near the vertices.  The resulting points are on a triangle in the x+y+z plane.  If you need unbiased choice of points in that triangle, scaling is no good.

The problem gets complicated in n-dimensions, but you can get a low-precision (but high accuracy, for all you laboratory science fans!) estimate by picking uniformly from the set of all n-tuples of non-negative integers adding up to N, and then dividing each of them by N.

I recently came up with an algorithm to do that for modest-sized n, N.  It should work for n=100 and N = 1,000,000 to give you 6-digit randoms.  See my answer at:

[Create constrained random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448417/create-constrained-random-numbers/18448874#18448874)

Comment: You should check out the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function).

Answer (score 6):

Create a list consisting of 0 and 1, then add 99 random numbers.  Sort the list.  Successive differences will be the lengths of intervals that add up to 1.

I'm not fluent in Python, so forgive me if there's a more Pythonic way of doing this.  I hope the intent is clear though:

```
import random

values = [0.0, 1.0]
for i in range(99):
    values.append(random.random())
values.sort()
results = []
for i in range(1,101):
    results.append(values[i] - values[i-1])
print results
```

---

Here's an updated implementation in Python 3:

```
import random

def sum_to_one(n):
    values = [0.0, 1.0] + [random.random() for _ in range(n - 1)]
    values.sort()
    return [values[i+1] - values[i] for i in range(n)]

print(sum_to_one(100))
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @pjs's solution we can define a function with two parameters as well.

```
import numpy as np

def sum_to_x(n, x):
    values = [0.0, x] + list(np.random.uniform(low=0.0,high=x,size=n-1))
    values.sort()
    return [values[i+1] - values[i] for i in range(n)]

sum_to_x(10, 0.6)
Out: 
[0.079058655684546,
 0.04168649034779022,
 0.09897491411670578,
 0.065152293196646,
 0.000544800901222664,
 0.12329662037166766,
 0.09562168167787738,
 0.01641359261155284,
 0.058273232428072474,
 0.020977718663918954]
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @sega_sai answer with an up-to-date and recommanded numpy implementation *[March 2022]*

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
rng.dirichlet(np.ones(10),size=1)
>>> array([[0.01279836, 0.16891858, 0.01136867, 0.17577222, 0.27944229,
        0.06244618, 0.19878224, 0.02481954, 0.01478089, 0.05087103]])
```

References:

- [Numpy Random Sampling documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#random-quick-start)
- [Random Generator Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng) & [Random Dirichlet generator Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.dirichlet.html#numpy.random.Generator.dirichlet)

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to have a minimum threshold for the randomly chosen numbers (i.e., the generated numbers should be atleast `min_thresh`),

```
rand_prop = 1 - num_of_values * min_thresh
random_numbers = (np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(10),size=1)[0] * rand_prop) + min_thresh
```

Just make sure that you have num_of_values (number of values to be generated) such that it is possible for generating required numbers (`num_values <= 1/min_thesh`)

So basically, we are fixing some portion of 1 for minimum threshold, then we create random numbers in other portion. We add `min_thesh` to all numbers to get sum 1.
For e.g: lets say you want to generate 3 numbers, with min_thresh=0.2. We create a portion to fill by random numbers [1 - (0.2x3) = 0.4]. We fill that portion and add 0.2 to all values, so we can get 0.6 filled too.

This is standard scaling and shifting used in random numbers generation theory. Credit goes to my friend Jeel Vaishnav (I am not sure if has SO profile) and @sega_sai.

Answer (score 1):

generate 100 random numbers doesn't matter what range.
sum the numbers generated, divide each individual by the total.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be using random.choice and divide by sum:

```
import random 
n = 5
rand_num = [random.choice(range(0,100)) for r in range(n)] # create random integers
rand_num = [i/sum(rand_num) for i in rand_num] # normalize them
```

Comment: Unfortunatley this makes the resulting random numbers linearly dependent: if you know $n-1$ of them then you know the $n$th as well. So the sequence isn't trully random. It's why I accpeted the Dirchlet distribution answer.

Comment: Thanks Tom Kealy for your comments on my answer. I will definitely check its linear dependencies, but also believe it should be an alternative solution for some applications, in particular, it might be useful when you want to have control over your numbers by simply adjusting the range(0,100). I agree to your point on Dirichlet random numbers, and it is definitely one of the best solutions.

Comment: You can control the resulting distribution by adjusting the $\alpha$ parameter of the Diriclet distribution. I really can't emphasise enough that it is the preffered solution - that's why I made it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do with:

```
r.append(1 - sum(r))
```

Comment: The last number is then correlated with the first `N-1` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of "divide each element in list by sum of list", this definition will create a list of random numbers of length = PARTS, sum = TOTAL, with each element rounded to PLACES (or None):

```
import random
import time

PARTS       = 5
TOTAL       = 10
PLACES      = 3

def random_sum_split(parts, total, places):

    a = []
    for n in range(parts):
        a.append(random.random())
    b = sum(a)
    c = [x/b for x in a]    
    d = sum(c)
    e = c
    if places != None:
        e = [round(x*total, places) for x in c]
    f = e[-(parts-1):]
    g = total - sum(f)
    if places != None:
        g = round(g, places)
    f.insert(0, g)

    log(a)
    log(b)
    log(c)
    log(d)
    log(e)
    log(f)
    log(g)

    return f   

def tick():

    if info.tick == 1:

        start = time.time()

        alpha = random_sum_split(PARTS, TOTAL, PLACES)

        log('********************')
        log('***** RESULTS ******')
        log('alpha: %s' % alpha)
        log('total: %.7f' % sum(alpha))
        log('parts: %s' % PARTS)
        log('places: %s' % PLACES)

        end = time.time()  

        log('elapsed: %.7f' % (end-start))
```

result:

```
Waiting...
Saved successfully.
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] [0.33561018369775897, 0.4904215932650632, 0.20264927800402832, 0.118862130636748, 0.03107818050878819]
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] 1.17862136611
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] [0.28474809073311597, 0.41609766067850096, 0.17193755673414868, 0.10084844382959707, 0.02636824802463724]
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] 1.0
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] [2.847, 4.161, 1.719, 1.008, 0.264]
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] [2.848, 4.161, 1.719, 1.008, 0.264]
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] 2.848
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] ********************
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] ***** RESULTS ******
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] alpha: [2.848, 4.161, 1.719, 1.008, 0.264]
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] total: 10.0000000
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] parts: 5
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] places: 3
[2014-06-13 00:01:00] elapsed: 0.0054131
```

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of pjs's method:

```
a = [0, total] + [random.random()*total for i in range(parts-1)]
a.sort()
b = [(a[i] - a[i-1]) for i in range(1, (parts+1))]
```

If you want them rounded to decimal places:

```
if places == None:
    return b
else:    
    b.pop()
    c = [round(x, places) for x in b]  
    c.append(round(total-sum(c), places))
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a list of `n` random numbers (with each value `>=a`) whose sum is `x` in Python.

- Generate a list of random numbers.

  `p = np.random.rand(n)`
- In case you want all the values greater than `a`

  `d = a + np.random.multinomial(x-a*n, p/np.sum(p))`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting query. The accepted answer is completely correct. But for those who do not understand why Dirichlet distribution produces better randomization than just dividing four random values by their sum, please read below explanation and example.

imagine you are to throw coins. if physical properties of two sides of the coin or your skill are even slightly biased to one side of the coin, after trying for certain number of times and recording your results, you will reach to a "probability function" that shows this bias clearly. but in computer programs this probability distribution is "evenly distributed" for the smallest possible decimals.
Taken this fact that the more you repeat the test, the better understanding of innate probability function you obtain and that computer probability function of a random number is almost evenly distributed, we see that in normalizing random parameters, N (total number of random numbers, here 4) is the deceiving parameter that makes probability function repeats itself. In other words, when you normalize 4 random parameters with the same probability function **you are shrinking their randomness by repeating the same hidden probability function 4 times in one dimension**. This problem is overcome by considering Dirichlet Distribution that considers multiple dimensions for probability functions so that they do not affect each other's probability. Still remember, you can't see this even distribution of probability by the first try but you know that exists somewhere in the program and it can show itself if you repeat the test again and again.

Below codes are an experiment to compare Dirichlet random parameters and Normalized random parameters. Copy and paste it and repeat the runs for several times (one instance is shown). You can see although Dirichlet D1 to D4 parameters change completely randomly where D1 to D4 all have a chance to become so little or so large, R1 to R4 normalized parameters change much more evenly. **This is a huge bug for many researchers' work who use random percentages for their initial parameters!**. All the best!

```
### Dirichlet distribution Randoms
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Dirichlet_distribution = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(4),size=1)   # dirichlet distribution produces normal probablity distribution of 4 possibilities when sum of them will be 1

labels = 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4'
sizes = [Dirichlet_distribution[0][0], Dirichlet_distribution[0][1], Dirichlet_distribution[0][2], Dirichlet_distribution[0][3]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2) # one row and two columns
ax[0].pie(sizes, labels=labels)
ax[0].set_title('Dirichlet distribution randomization', fontsize=11)

# Normalized 4 random numbers
r= np.random.rand(1,4) # 1,4 is just the shape, all cells are random values from 0 to +1
r1 = r[0][0]
r2 = r[0][1]
r3 = r[0][2]
r4 = r[0][3]
N = r1+r2+r3+r4
r1 = r1/N
r2 = r1/N
r3 = r1/N
r4 = r1/N

labels_ = 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4'
sizes_ = [r1, r2, r3, r4]

ax[1].pie(sizes_, labels=labels_)
ax[1].set_title('normalized randomization', fontsize=11)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let R(n) be the set of n random numbers. Now concider the set Q(n) which also consists of n elements and each element is defined by the function f(n) = R(n)/( R(0)+R(1)+....R(n)). That new set's sum is 1. Note that the elements of the set Q are probably not distributed as "randomly" as the first's set's elements, ex let's say R(n) consists of numbers 100<x<1000000 each one of them will map to a number less than one so if you have x1=256, x2=512 they will map to z1=1/256 and z2=1/512. From my testing the smaller the upper limit on the initial set the better the distribution on the second set.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).