# python dictionary, assign random values the sum of which is a certain value

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I am making a python program in which random values are generated *n* times, to be used as parameter values for model simulation.

I have a dictionary defining the boundaries for each parameter, for example:

```
parameters = {'A': random.uniform(1,10), 'B': random.uniform(20,40)}
```

I want to add some parameters the sum of which has to be 1, something like:

```
params = {'C1': random.uniform(0.0,1.0), 'C2': 1 - params['C1']}
```

This latter obviously doesn't work producing the `KeyError: 'C1'`

I also tried something like:

```
params = {'A': random.uniform(1,10), 'B': random.uniform(20,40), 'C': {'C1': None,'C2': None}}

def class_fractions():
    for key in params['C']:
        if key == 'C1':
            params['C'][key] = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
        if key == 'C2':
            params['C'][key] = 1.0 - params['C'][key]
```

but after calling the function I get the TypeError

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your for loop will not work, because dict does not garantee order. So C2 can be executed before C1.

Comment: `params['C']['C2']` is always `None`. Never assigned a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your use of the `for` loop it looks like you may really have many more parameters than just two. In that case you can generate a list of values filled with random numbers, and *then* scale it to sum to one, [as described in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659948/320036). Then iterate over a zipped view of your dictionary keys and the list items and assign the items to the dictionary.

Or, operating directly on the dictionary:

```
params = {k: random.uniform(0, 1) for k in ('C1', 'C2', 'C3')}
total = sum(params.values())
params = {k: (v / total) for k, v in params.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is because `dict` are not ordered in Python. When you do:

```
for key in params['C']
```

You are getting `C2` key before than `C1`. Actually you do not even need to iterate the `dict` simply set values in the dict like:

```
def class_fractions():
    params['C']['C1'] = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
    params['C']['C2'] = 1.0 - params['C']['C1']
```

Yo do not even need separate function as it updates only the same dict, simply you do it like:

```
params = {'A': random.uniform(1,10), 'B': random.uniform(20,40)} # create partial dict
c_dict = {'C1': random.uniform(1,10)}  # create sub-dict to store random value
c_dict['C2'] = 1 - c_dict['C1']  # get value that you want
params['C'] = c_dict       # add entry into parent dict
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want ot use your class_fraction, and initialize params at once, then need to use OrderDict:

```
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

params = {'A': random.uniform(1,10), 'B': random.uniform(20,40), 'C':OrderedDict([('C1', None),('C2', None)])}


def class_fractions():
    for key in params['C']:
        if key == 'C1':
            params['C'][key] = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
        if key == 'C2':
            params['C'][key] = 1.0 - params['C']['C1']


class_fractions()
print(params)
```

Results in:

```
{'B': 37.3088618142464, 'A': 2.274415152225316, 'C': OrderedDict([('C1', 0.12703200100786471), ('C2', 0.8729679989921353)])}
```