# Summing a list of random variables to 1 under a given constraint

Tags: python-3.x, random

l would like to generate 6 random variables between 0 and 1 **[0,1]** and deduce the seventh from the sum of the six values.
For instance we have :

```
alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,alpha5,alpha6
```

are generated randomly in this interval [0,1]. Now l would like to deduce `alpha7` as follow :

```
sum(alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,alpha5,alpha6)+ alpha7 =1
```

hence :

```
alpha7= 1-sum(alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,alpha5,alpha6)
```

l did the following :

```
>>> r = numpy.random.random(6) 
>>> r
array([ 0.7415801 ,  0.43230563,  0.29287991,  0.41897992,  0.54627315,
        0.4071017 ])
>>> r.sum()
2.8391204236894456
alpha7=1-r.sum()
-1.8391204236894456
```

However it violates :

```
sum(alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,alpha5,alpha6)+ alpha7 =1
```

because `sum(alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,alpha5,alpha6)`  should be less than 1 and alpha7 is in [0,1] such that

```
**sum(alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,alpha5,alpha6)+ alpha7 =1**
```

Comment: Why not pick seven random numbers, add them together and scale all of them such that the total is 1?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the purpose is to deduce the seventh value value from the the sum of the first six values

Comment: That doesn't really seem like a purpose; that's what you're trying to do, but not why you're trying to do it. What's the actual *context*?

Comment: The context is to infer a random variable from the sum of a set of random variables such that all the random variables sums to 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a list of random numbers, summing to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1)

Comment: @glibdud, the solution suggested there is to generate 7 random variable and divide b their sum to get the sum to 1

Comment: @Joseph You may need to explain a bit more what the desired properties are of your numbers. It appears to me that you're just trying to generate 7 random numbers that sum to 1, in an odd, roundabout sort of way.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a sequence which has sum between 0 and 1 you can use this:

```
alphas = np.random.random(6)
alphas = alphas/sum(alphas)*np.random.rand()
```

`alphas/sum(alphas)` will make them sum to 1 and `np.random.rand()` will factor them between 0 and 1.

Comment: 1) your solution generates 6 random variables andand don't add an deduce the  the seventh  random variable. 2) the sum of your alphas is not equal to 1

Comment: I have explained which part is equal to 1 and which part changes it to be between 0 and 1. This solves your problem, and that is what SO is for, not for writing whole code.