# Generate random integers with two constraints (sum and local maximum) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, random, sum, constraints

I have a dataframe where I want to create random numbers in a new column. The random numbers must fulfill two constraints:

1. The random numbers must add up to a specified sum (in the example, the sum is 300)
2. For each observation, the random numbers must **not** exceed a value in the constraint column.

In the example below, the constraints are fulfilled because the sum is 300 and the random number does not exceed the constraint column.

**Example:**

| GEOID | CONSTRAINT | RANDOM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 010010000001 | 100 | 80 |
| 010010000002 | 50 | 40 |
| 010010000003 | 75 | 60 |
| 010010000004 | 75 | 60 |
| 010010000005 | 100 | 60 |

It seems having [random numbers totaling a sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1) has been demonstrated but I do not see an example with a second constraint.

**Edit for clarity:** The new column must be integers. The minimum lower bound value is 0.

Comment: What happens if the numbers cannot add up to sum due to constraints?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny are you suggesting floats instead? I suppose that would work if the floats could be transformed into integers with and not violate either of the constraints.

Comment: @DaniMesejo then the attempt is not a solution.

Comment: I expressed myself poorly. Let's try with an example: if all constraint equals 10 and the sum is 300 then there is no solution for your problem

Comment: @adin So you're confirming to Michael that the outcomes have to be integers?  It's a yes/no question.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I think so too, but by not actually saying "yes" the response remained ambiguous so I'd like to pin it down.  There's also been no discussion of whether there's a lower bound.  Can values go negative?

Comment: I think something like: `res = rng.multinomial(300, df["CONSTRAINT"] / df["CONSTRAINT"].sum(), size=1)` may work well for integers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an efficient way to generate N random integers in a range that have a given sum or average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393463/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-generate-n-random-integers-in-a-range-that-have-a-g)

Comment: In particular, the first edit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525097/815724

Comment: @adin According to your current wording, solutions [100, -50, 75, 75, 100], [100, 50, -25, 75, 100], or [100, 50, 75, -25, 100] would all meet your requirements.  Is that correct, or are there lower bounds as well?

Comment: @DaniMesejo - That's brilliant, I only get 2% violations of the second constraint. That's very well suited for rejection sampling with 98% success on first try.

Comment: @pjs thank you for bringing that up, I edited the original question for clarity that the lower bound is zero.

Comment: @DaniMesejo can you please put `res = rng.multinomial(300, df["CONSTRAINT"] / df["CONSTRAINT"].sum(), size=1)` in a formal answer and explain how it works? I tried 100 groups of 1000 attempts using that answer and found that on average, I rejected 23% of the results because one of the results was greater than a constraint. Since I can check for valid attempts, and each iteration was quick, this solution works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [multinomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.multinomial.html#numpy.random.Generator.multinomial) distribution to build an *approximate* answer:

```
def sample(total, constraints):
    import numpy as np
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    samples = rng.multinomial(total, constraints / constraints.sum(), size=100)
    return next(val for val in samples if np.all(val < constraints))


df["RANDOM"] = sample(300, df["CONSTRAINT"].values)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
             GEOID  CONSTRAINT  RANDOM
0  10010000001         100      81
1  10010000002          50      42
2  10010000003          75      57
3  10010000004          75      53
4  10010000005         100      67
```

Thanks goes to [@Michael Szczesny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny) for testing the solution.

The key to solve this, relies in (quote from numpy docs):

> Its values, X_i = [X_0, X_1, ..., X_p], represent the number of times
> the outcome was i.

see more details in this [blog post](http://sunny.today/generate-random-integers-with-fixed-sum/).