# Create a list of N random numbers with max and min value and total sum

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, sum

I'm trying to create a list (call it: weights) of N random numbers between 0.005 and 0.045 with a total sum equal to 1. N can be any integer between 22 and 200. So the following restrictions:

- Number of numbers in weights = N
- For every n in weights: 0.005 < n < 0.045
- sum of all n's in weights = 1

The first restriction is easy I think. Also, I know how to fix both the second and the third restriction separate from each other. But I don't know how to combine them into one piece of code.

- Second restriction: 0.005 < x < 0.045:

```
import numpy as np
import random


weights_step1 = np.random.randint(min=5, max = 45, size = N)

weights = []
for weight in weights_step1:
  weights.append(weight/1000)
```

- Third restriction

[Generating a list of random numbers, summing to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1)

Does anyone know how to get both restrictions into one piece of code?

Comment: What if N is less than 22 or larger than 200?

Comment: It looks there is a flaw in your problem, if N can be arbitrary and the weights can only be from  0.005 to 0.045, if I give N like 5 you can't satisfy your problem anyway.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, you're right. In my situation it is for a portfolio with N somewhere around 50

Comment: @Bruno i'll edit the post, my N is somewhere around 50

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but just a heads up that no (pseudo) random distribution can be constrained to a required sum.

Comment: @JonSG Huh?! Dirichlet distribution is the perfect example of being constrained to a required sum

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux There is no way that the final item in the list is random if you have a target sum

Comment: @DirkKoomen If you have say N=200, and sum=1, then mean value of each n is 1/200=0.005. But this is MEAN value, meaning some n would be below 0.005 and some above. You cannot have N=200, sum=1 and no value below 0.005. You could have N=200, sum=1 and values of n grouped close to 0.005 with relatively small variance.

Comment: @JonSG Sure, there is a way. In Dirichlet sample all values would be random, with constrain of sum=1. Problem is getting say N=200, and sum=1. Mean would be 0.005, but some values in the sample would be above 0.005, some would be below 0.005, you cannot have all of them >= 0.005

Comment: Just a little bit of consideration: This is a kind of problem that might or might not finish, since the generated numbers might never satisfy the condition. You can have the program running and by a matter of luck get your results or it might run indefinetely. Are you aware of it?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the [Dirichlet Rescale algorithm (DRS)](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/167646/), for which a [Python implementation](https://pypi.org/project/drs/) is available:

That gives you a proper statistical guarantee. Quoting the abstract of the math paper:

> the vectors are uniformly distributed over the valid region of the domain of all possible vectors, bounded by the constraints.

Trying for 50 numbers summing to 1:

```
$ pip install drs
...
Installing collected packages: drs
Successfully installed drs-2.0.0
$ 
$ python3
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 19 2021, 00:00:00) 
...
>>>
>>> from drs import drs
>>>
>>> n = 50
>>> s = 1.0
>>>
>>> v1 = drs(n, s, n*[0.045], n*[0.005])
>>> sum(v1)
1.0000000000000004
>>> max(v1)
0.04278387127251347
>>> min(v1)
0.005035400173241331
>>> 
>>> v2 = drs(n, s, n*[0.045], n*[0.005])
>>> sum(v2)
0.9999999999999994
>>> max(v2)
0.04445793844097045
>>> min(v2)
0.005294943276519565
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick. The strategy is to uniformly partition the available space then iterate over the partitions and for each iteration take a random bit from the current one and add it to a second one.

You might find that you need to use the `decimal` package to get a little more precision. You will likely also want to introduce guards to ensure that the constraints on the number of partitions and their minimum and maximum sizes are not inconsistent.

```
import random

partitions = 45
partition_size_min = 0.005
partition_size_max = 0.045

weights = [1.0 / partitions] * partitions
for index in range(len(weights)):
    partner_index = random.randint(0, partitions-1)

    available_to_give = weights[index] - partition_size_min
    available_to_recieve = partition_size_max - weights[partner_index]
    delta = random.uniform(0, min(available_to_give, available_to_recieve))

    weights[partner_index] += delta
    weights[index] -= delta

print(f"Sum: {sum(weights)} Min:{min(weights)} Max: {max(weights)}")
print(weights)
```

That should give you a result like:

```
Sum: 1.0 Min:0.0057759435106850415 Max: 0.04428043727891049

[
    0.03408561328744241,
    0.010644787590344313,
    0.01400427089495221,
    0.01484912512559225,
    ...
    0.019186499047958494,
    0.02443794812733188,
    0.03475172101526412,
    0.020782296753987052
]
```

I'm sure a proper statistician would find a fault in this method, but it might get you close to what you want.