# Applying a formula or distribution when creating a column instead of dividing values equal across rows

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, distribution

I'm working on building a visualization but have across an issue. I'm currently creating a column called Labor per Week which takes the total hours which are estimated and divides it by the number of weeks a record takes. This divides the total hours equally for the duration of the project.

| Job Number | # of weeks | Week Count | Total Hours | Labor per Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 5 | 1 | 20 | 4 |
| 00001 | 5 | 2 | 20 | 4 |
| 00001 | 5 | 3 | 20 | 4 |
| 00001 | 5 | 4 | 20 | 4 |
| 00001 | 5 | 5 | 20 | 4 |
| 00002 | 10 | 1 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 2 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 3 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 4 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 5 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 6 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 7 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 8 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 9 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 10 | 100 | 10 |

I have historical data I can use to find the mean and standard deviation for jobs.

Is it possible to create a Labor per Week column that can have a formula applied to it so it resembles more more normal distribution instead of dividing hours equal across all weeks?

| Job Number | # of weeks | Week Count | Total Hours | Labor per Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 5 | 1 | 20 | 3 |
| 00001 | 5 | 2 | 20 | 4 |
| 00001 | 5 | 3 | 20 | 6 |
| 00001 | 5 | 4 | 20 | 4 |
| 00001 | 5 | 5 | 20 | 3 |
| 00002 | 10 | 1 | 100 | 8 |
| 00002 | 10 | 2 | 100 | 8 |
| 00002 | 10 | 3 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 4 | 100 | 12 |
| 00002 | 10 | 5 | 100 | 12 |
| 00002 | 10 | 6 | 100 | 12 |
| 00002 | 10 | 7 | 100 | 12 |
| 00002 | 10 | 8 | 100 | 10 |
| 00002 | 10 | 9 | 100 | 8 |
| 00002 | 10 | 10 | 100 | 8 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a list of random numbers, summing to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1). Looks like all you need is to rescale to the desired sum rather than 1.