# generate random integers with fixed sum and constraints

Tags: random

How to generate 6 random integers which add up to 8, and each one is less than or equal to 2?

eg. 1,2,1,2,2,0

For far I have found the method which give the random integers with fixed sum but how to impose the constraints on these integers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622608/choosing-n-numbers-with-fixed-sum http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8574/generating-n-unique-random-numbers-with-a-specific-sum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions about the probability distribution of the numbers?

Comment: I am using either Matlab or python.

Comment: No restriction about the distribution of the numbers, but uniform distribution of the sequences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create constrained random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448417/create-constrained-random-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a hit-and-miss approach to guarantee a uniform distribution of generated sequences satisfying the constraint. It is easy to work out that the probability of 6 random integers in {0,1,2} adding up to 8 is roughly 12.3%, so not too many trials are needed before a hit. Here is a Python implementation:

```
import random

def randNums(n,a,b,s):
    #finds n random ints in [a,b] with sum of s
    hit = False
    while not hit:
        total, count = 0,0
        nums = []
        while total < s and count < n:
            r = random.randint(a,b)
            total += r
            count += 1
            nums.append(r)
        if total == s and count == n: hit = True
    return nums
```

Here is the output from 5 runs:

```
>>> for i in range(5): print(randNums(6,0,2,8))

[2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]
[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

On Edit: I was curious about the exact probabilities so wrote a program to exhaustively enumerate all possibilities. Random sequences of length 6 in {0,1,2} can be thought of as random integers in 0 to 3^6-1 = 728 written in base 3. Just calculate the digit sums for base-3 numbers in that range and see which = 8:

```
def toBase3(n):
    digits = []
    q,r = divmod(n,3)
    while q > 0:
        digits.append(r)
        q,r = divmod(q,3)
    digits.append(r)
    return ''.join(str(i) for i in reversed(digits))

def dsum(s):
    return sum(int(d) for d in s)

hits = []
for n in range(729):
    s = toBase3(n)
    if dsum(s) == 8: hits.append(s)

hits = [('0'*(6-len(s)))+s for s in hits] #left-pad with '0' if needed

s = ''.join(hits)

print("%d valid sequences for prob. of %f" % (len(hits),len(hits)/3.0**6))
print("%d zeros in those sequences for a prob. of %f" % (s.count('0'),s.count('0')/540.0))
print("%d ones in those sequences for a prob. of %f" % (s.count('1'),s.count('1')/540.0))
print("%d twos in those sequences for a prob. of %f" % (s.count('2'),s.count('2')/540.0))
```

Output:

```
90 valid sequences for prob. of 0.123457
90 zeros in those sequences for a prob. of 0.166667
180 ones in those sequences for a prob. of 0.333333
270 twos in those sequences for a prob. of 0.500000
```

As an odd curiosity, the probability that such a random sequence of length 6 sums to 8, with more decimal places displayed, is

```
90/729 = 0.123456790 (repeating)
```

I didn't realize that there was such a nice probability interpretation of the pleasing decimal `0.1234567`. It's a pity that `8` isn't after the `7`.

Comment: Note that this will generate a uniform distribution of sequences (across all possible sequences), the individual numbers themselves will not be uniformly distributed (and I don't think they can be, given the constraints).

Comment: @Thilo Yes -- you are right. I ran the program 10000 times (for a total of 60000 numbers). Roughly 16% were 0, 36% were 1 and 48% were 2. I didn't expect the distributions of the numbers themselves to be that far from uniform.

Comment: Yes, the uniform distribution of sequences across all possible sequences is what I need. Thank you!!

Comment: There is a better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448874/472610

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

1. start the array with all zeros.
2. randomly choose an array index, and add one to that position in the array. If it is already at two, don't do it, retry until it succeeds.
3. do step 2 eight times

This will not result in uniformly distributed integers on [0,2] (but you did not say what distribution you need), the numbers will skew towards equal heights across the array.

Comment: This is really quite clever. I wonder what the distribution is since I suspect that you are right that it is skewed.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Two more posits: a) I am almost sure that this will result in a different distribution than your method. b) I am inclined to think that your method also results in numbers that are skewed towards the average (but maybe not so much toward equal heights, if that makes sense)

Comment: Since I throw away vectors as soon as I detect a constraint violation and then begin from scratch in the next pass through the loop, I don't think I introduce any bias, though I could be wrong.

Comment: There is no bias in your selection. You will get a uniform distribution of sequences among all possible sequences. But the numbers themselves should be skewed towards the average (by virtue of more such numbers being included in the possible sequences, or conversely by relatively more extreme numbers being included in the impossible sequences).

Comment: Thanks John and Thilo for sharing your ideas, I agree with John.

Answer (score 2):

First, not all of it can be truly random, since those requirements make a few things necessary.

For example, there MUST be at least two 2's in order for 6 total numbers from the set {0,1,2} to make it to 8. So two of our end integers are preordained. May as well not waste energy figuring them out because of that. So that starts us off at 2,2,?,?,?,?.

Now that leaves us with a challenge consisting of getting 4 numbers from the set {0,1,2} that equal 4. The possible combinations for that are (not counting the 0's) two 2's, one 2 and two 1's, and four 1's. Literally only 3 possible combos. So it makes sense to just set them into an array and pick one at random...and those arrays can start with the two 2's we already know will be needed. So:

```
var possibles = [
    [2,2,2,2,0,0],
    [2,2,2,1,1,0],
    [2,2,1,1,1,1]
];

var randomInd = Math.floor( Math.random()*possibles.length ); // random number from 0-2
var myArr = possibles[randomInd]; // picks a random entry from possibles
```

Now that we've got a random Array consisting of the possible ways it could go down, we just have to shuffle it up. We can use a standard shuffling function for that:

```
function shuffle(arr)
{
    var curInd = arr.length, tempVal, randInd;
    while (0 !== curInd) {
        randInd = Math.floor(Math.random()*curInd);
        curInd -= 1;
        tempVal = arr[curInd];
        arr[curInd] = arr[randInd];
        arr[randInd] = tempVal;
    }
}

shuffle(myArr);
alert(myArr); // will give "random" sequence
```

You could also "weight" certain combinations by better representing them in the `possibles` array (i.e. make 2 entries of a certain combo instead of 1).

**Note** - I don't see any specific language required, so for anyone curious that's javascript. A JSFiddle can be seen of it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/6xaeLp4g/

Comment: Hmm. With proper weights, this should result in the same distribution as John's method. But how to arrive at the weights?

Comment: Good observation about the need for there to be at least two 2s

Comment: @Thilo - I didn't math it, but I'd guess that doubling up on the middle one (the one with 1 zero) would do it.