# Breaking a number into two random parts

Tags: python-3.x

I have a number, let, 17. I want to randomly break it into two parts, in such a way that sum of these parts give the result 17. Eg. 13 + 4, 12 + 5...But I also want that these two parts must not have 2 as a number.
Any algorithm or code in Python. Please help.

Comment: 2 as a digit or 2 as a number?  any attempt from you?

Comment: For a given number `n`, you're trying to generate numbers `2 < x < n-2` and `n-x`?

Comment: The essential idea of how to do constrained randomization in python is in this other question, but for a different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448417/create-constrained-random-numbers

Comment: 2 as a number @wim

Comment: Yes sir @Patrick

Comment: So you don't want 0 or 1? Or you do?

Comment: I wanted two numbers but those numbers must not be 2..

Answer (score 1):

Use random.randint() to generate the first number and then subtract it from n, we got the second number. The if else statement make sure neither of num1 and num2 is equal to 2. Hope this is helping!

```
import random

def break_num(n):

    while True:

        num1 = random.randint(1, n - 1)
        num2 = n - num1

        if num1 != 2 and num2 != 2:
            break
        else:
            continue

    print(f'{num1} + {num2}')
```